# what is the number that it shows when I print out the **this** pointer in java?

Tags: java

This program

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public void testFunc(){
        System.out.println("Class = "+this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
        hw.testFunc();
    }
}
```

gives me this output:

```
Hello, World
Class = HelloWorld@7c6768
```

What does `@7c6768` after HelloWorld in the second line mean?

Comment: hashCode of HelloWorld Class

Comment: It returns the toString() of the object. If not overidden, that will be classname@hashcode in hexa

Comment: @KanagarajM not of the _class_, but of that _instance_ of the class.

Comment: yes @jlordo i forgot to mention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[As per Docs of toString() method in Object class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

When

```
 getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

When you call toString() on object ,If you [**ovveride**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) like below ,you get  your own implementation

```
 @Override
  public String toString() {
     //return something 
  }
```

Otherwise gives the default implementation,which you are seeing right now

[From Object class Source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Object.java)

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.
>
> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>    getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())

```
Returns:
a string representation of the object.


    public String  toString() {
         return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
     }
```

Comment: I just wanted to add: you can override the toString() method in that object in order to print something more meaningful.

Comment: Yeah if I define a function as `@Override
 public String toString(){
  return "TEST";
 }
 ` it shows me TEST instead of the default value.

Answer (score 13):

Object's `toString()` is implemented as follows:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Since your `HelloWorld` class doesn't override it, this is the method called.

Comment: I'm sorry but I want to ask a very basic question that I just seem to understand: In your code when you say `getClass().getName()`, which class do getClass() and getName() belong to? Is getClass()a member function of the class in which this toString() function is defined? If so then where does getName() come from?

Comment: Every class in Java extends `Object`, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html That's why every class also has the `getClass()` method.

Answer (score 9):

The `toString()` method returns a string representation of the object.

In general, the `toString()` method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.

The `toString` method for `class Object` returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

```
 getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Answer (score 3):

From the API:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object

Answer (score 3):

HelloWorld@7c6768 is a string representation of the current object, and @7c6768 is a hashcode. In fact you are invoking toString() of current object

Here is java doc for toString() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()

Answer (score 3):

If you see the toString() method in Object class

```
/**
 * Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
 * {@code toString} method returns a string that
 * "textually represents" this object. The result should
 * be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a
 * person to read.
 * It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.
 * <p>
 * The {@code toString} method for class {@code Object}
 * returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the
 * object is an instance, the at-sign character `{@code @}', and
 * the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the
 * object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the
 * value of:
 * <blockquote>
 * <pre>
 * getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
 * </pre></blockquote>
 *
 * @return  a string representation of the object.
 */
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

It returns Class name followed by its hash code. That is the number you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

That is `this.hashCode()`. Since you do not redefine `hashCode()`, this number is the memory address in the JVM where the object is stored.

Answer (score 2):

Look inside Objects' toString() method:

```
   public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
   }
```

It is a hash value of the object.

Answer (score 2):

The number that identifies the object uniquely. It is Hexadecimal representation of hashcode. In simple terms, the whole String printed is the reference returned after instantiating the class.