# Read property of objects in array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a array of objects. When I print it, it looks like :

```
[com.groups.bean.User@5a2045, com.groups.bean.User@fcabd6, com.groups.bean.User@758cdb]
```

I want array of values of its property "Name" like :

```
[John,Mike,Peter]
```

I know, I can iterate through the array and call property "Name" of each object and put it in a new array.

But I want to avoid looping. Is there any shortcut for it ?

Comment: [what is the number that it shows when I print out the **this** pointer in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878457/what-is-the-number-that-it-shows-when-i-print-out-the-this-pointer-in-java)

Comment: override toString() method for the User class to return Name

Comment: you need to Owerride toString() in your class. Now works toString() of Object class, why this looks next - `com.groups.bean.User@5a2045`.

Comment: Overload toString method in your User class and within it return name property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override `toString()` method in your `User` object:

```
public class User {
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

You can write it w/o `@Override`, though. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) you can find documentation on this annotation.

Comment: A small improvement, `@Ovveride` :)

Answer (score 2):

Override the `toString()` method of `User`.