# Trying to compare rep sales in an array list in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Ok so here is my issue. I am trying to compare the annual sales of two or more sales reps in an ArrayList and am getting some strange results that I just can't figure out. I have to compare the two, then tell the user how much the rep with the lower sales needs to sell to take the lead. I have it broken into three classes. But I'm pretty sure this act is dependent on just two of those. The first is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author Cameron
 */
public class SalesRep {

private ArrayList<CompensationCalculator> pool;

public SalesRep(){

    pool = new ArrayList<>();

}

public void setPool(ArrayList<CompensationCalculator> pool){

    this.pool = pool;

}

public ArrayList<CompensationCalculator> getPool(){

    return pool;

}

public void addToPool(CompensationCalculator salesRep){

    pool.add(salesRep);

}

public String toString(String report){

    double diff;

    for(int i=0; i<pool.size(); i++){

        if (pool.get(i).getSales() < pool.get(i++).getSales()){

            diff = pool.get(i++).getSales() - pool.get(i).getSales();
            report = pool.get(i).getName() + "needs to sell " +
                    diff + " to take the lead.";
        }            

        if (pool.get(i).getSales() > pool.get(i++).getSales()){

            diff = pool.get(i).getSales() - pool.get(i++).getSales();
            report = pool.get(i++).getName() + "needs to sell " +
                    diff + " to take the lead.";
        }  

        }
    return report;
    }
}
```

That class should compare the two reps in the array while this one displays it to the user:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AnnualSales {

public static void main(String[] args){

    CompensationCalculator test = new CompensationCalculator(); //Creates a new instance of the class
    SalesRep testName = new SalesRep(); //Creates a new instance of the SalesRep class
    String cont = new String(); //A string to represent if there ar emore names to be added

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //Allows for user input to be read

    while (!cont.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){

        System.out.println("What is the name of the sales representative? ");
            test.setName(scan.next());

        System.out.println("Please enter " + test.getName() +
                "'s annual sales: ");
            test.setSales(scan.nextDouble());

        testName.addToPool(test);

        System.out.println("Are there any more sales representatives you "
                + "would like to add? ");
            cont = scan.next();

        } 

    System.out.print(testName.getPool());
    System.out.print(testName.toString());
    }
}
```

Now there are no errors being found, the program compiles and executes without a problem. But as a result I get

`[compensationcalculator.CompensationCalculator@55f96302, compensationcalculator.CompensationCalculator@55f96302]compensationcalculator.SalesRep@3d4eac69'

I am extremely confused and have been working on just this method for three hours so I am sure I need a fresh pair of eyes. Any help or guidance would be amazing.

EDIT:

Ok so your suggestion to use a Comparator was deffinetely helpful. I was also confusing myself with unnecessary code so I reworked it a bit and now it is working except for one aspect. Here is the code that I changed:

```
public String compare(SalesRep rep1, SalesRep rep2){

    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    Double diff;

    if (rep1.getSales() > rep2.getSales()){
        diff = rep1.getSales() - rep2.getSales();
        return rep2.getName() + " needs to sell " + fmt.format(diff) +
                " to take the lead.";}
    else{
        diff = rep2.getSales() - rep1.getSales();
       return rep1.getName() + " needs to sell " + fmt.format(diff) +
               " to take the lead.";}                 
       }
```

I also renamed my classes to better organize them to account for the new requirements. Now the only problem is that it is giving a difference of the two sales as $0.0 no madder what I input. Am I calling on each objects sales incorrectly? I feel like I have run into this problem before but reviewing my past code isn't highlighting what I am doing wrong.

Comment: [Click me ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878457/what-is-the-number-that-it-shows-when-i-print-out-the-this-pointer-in-java/17878495#17878495)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you call `toString(String)` but only `toString()`, that's why you'd get that "stange" output.

Btw, that `report` parameter of your `toString(String)` method seems quite odd, since you're not using it besides assignments. You should use a local variable in that case.

Another potential error:

```
if (pool.get(i).getSales() > pool.get(i++).getSales()){
  diff = pool.get(i).getSales() - pool.get(i++).getSales();
  report = pool.get(i++).getName() + "needs to sell " +
           diff + " to take the lead.";
}
```

Here you are incrementing `i` three times, so you'd refer to 3 different indices in `pool`.
Suppose `i = 0`, then you'd get:

```
//the first i++ returns i (0) and then increments i to 1
if (pool.get(0).getSales() > pool.get(0).getSales()){
  //here i is 1, thus the next i++ returns 1 and increments i to 2
  diff = pool.get(1).getSales() - pool.get(1).getSales();
  //here i is 2, so the next i++ returns 2 and increments i to 3 
  report = pool.get(2).getName() + "needs to sell " +
           diff + " to take the lead.";
}
```

So in that second case you'd add 3 to `i` and thus advance the loop by 4, since the `i++` in the loop's head also increments i once more. I'd suggest you use `i + 1` in your loop body instead of `i++`.

Besides that, your design is quite odd, since class `CompensationCalculator` actually seems to define a sales rep.

Another thing: I'd probably sort the list of sales reps in descending order (hint: use a `Comparator`). Then element 0 would be the sales rep with the highest sales and the last element would be the sales rep with the lowest sales. Difference calculations would then be a piece of cake.

Answer (score 0):

The `toString` that you are calling is the method inherited from Object.  The `toString` method that you defined takes a `String` parameter.

```
System.out.print(testName.toString());
```

so override the proper method.

or use the returned `String` from your method.

```
String out;
 out = testName.toString(out);  // Strings are immutable
```

Answer (score 0):

Add @override annotation to your toString method and move report in, lie so:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
  String report;
  .....
}
```